# Stacked density chart from SQL query

Tags: r, ggplot2, stacked

I have a result from an SQL query that looks like this (a test query with no particular meaning):

```
 week       cash      ccard      fcard      mobile     total   
    9       3.45       0.00       0.00       0.00       3.45
   10      13.02      17.18       4.32      21.24      55.76
   11      47.61      24.52      12.32      32.18     116.63
   12      21.32      61.96      17.32       1.40     102.00
   13     181.80       1.70     275.20       3.50     462.20
   14     390.14     191.80      10.08     100.40     692.42
   15     102.40     207.80     101.40       0.00     411.60
```

The result of this query goes into a data frame which I want to plot as a stacked density chart where 'week' should be on the X axis and Y axies would be fractions 'cash/total', 'ccard/total' and so on. How would I do that? I googled but all the examples I found so far do not seem to applicable to SQL outputs.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: (Sergei, I edited the question to remove the pipes/lines of the ascii table; it generally makes it easier for us to just highlight, copy, then `read.table(header=TRUE, "clipboard")` (or similar) to get at the data, vice manually cutting out all of the boundaries. If you prefer, feel free to rollback my edit. Thanks!)

Comment: @r2evans - how did you change all the formatting?

Comment: @RyanJohn, I highlighted, copied, then `writeLines(gsub("\\|", " ", readLines("clipboard"))[-2], "clipboard")`, and pasted. (In this case it was easy, so I just did it.)

Comment: I was trying to solve the question, but getting the data was the hardest part!

Comment: (Sergei, did you see that?!? Format the data for easy consumption supports faster answers. Instant validation of my suggested edit :-)

Comment: Yeah. Thanks. In this case it would be easier to change the SQL statement to just group by pay type. The query is much simpler and it would go right into R.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, `ggplot2` prefers data to be in a "long" format, where it is currently in a "wide" format. In SQL terms, this is a `PIVOT`, though I find using `tidyr::pivot_*` and `data.table::melt` and `::dcast` to be much easier to use than in SQL.

By that, I mean:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr) # just for pivot_longer
dat <- pivot_longer(dat, cash:mobile) %>%
  mutate(pct = (value / total))
dat
# # A tibble: 28 x 5
#     week  total name   value    pct
#    <int>  <dbl> <chr>  <dbl>  <dbl>
#  1     9   3.45 cash    3.45 1     
#  2     9   3.45 ccard   0    0     
#  3     9   3.45 fcard   0    0     
#  4     9   3.45 mobile  0    0     
#  5    10  55.8  cash   13.0  0.234 
#  6    10  55.8  ccard  17.2  0.308 
#  7    10  55.8  fcard   4.32 0.0775
#  8    10  55.8  mobile 21.2  0.381 
#  9    11 117.   cash   47.6  0.408 
# 10    11 117.   ccard  24.5  0.210 
# # ... with 18 more rows
```

With that, you can do

```r
library(ggplot2)
# library(scales) # percent
ggplot(dat, aes(week, pct, fill=name)) +
  geom_density(position="fill", stat="identity") +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent)
```

[image: ggplot2 stacked density]

(I should add that the "density" nature of this plot is a little deceiving: there is the suggestion of data in between the weekly points. Since the x-axis is effectively discrete with a low "n", I'd suggest a barplot as @RyanJohn suggests.)

Answer (score 1):

Here's bar chart - if you'd like that instead.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(scales)

df1 <- structure(list(week = c(9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15), cash = c(3.45, 
13.02, 47.61, 21.32, 181.8, 390.14, 102.4), ccard = c(0, 17.18, 
24.52, 61.96, 1.7, 191.8, 207.8), fcard = c(0, 4.32, 12.32, 17.32, 
275.2, 10.08, 101.4), mobile = c(0, 21.24, 32.18, 1.4, 3.5, 100.4, 
0), total = c(3.45, 55.76, 116.63, 102, 462.2, 692.42, 411.6)), class = c("spec_tbl_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -7L), spec = structure(list(
cols = list(week = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector")), cash = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector")), ccard = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector")), fcard = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector")), mobile = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector")), total = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
"collector")), skip = 1), class = "col_spec"))

df1 %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = c(-week, -total),
               names_to = "type",
               values_to = "amount") %>% 
  mutate(pct = amount / total) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(week, pct, fill = type))+
  geom_col() +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent_format())+
  labs(title = "% spend by payment type")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-08-12 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: I think I prefer the barplot over the density plot in this example, nice thinking.

Comment: (I think `position="stack"` is the default for `geom_col`, so you could leave that off.)

Comment: You're correct @r2evans. Per `?geom_col` - "By default, multiple bars occupying the same x position will be stacked atop one another by 'position_stack()'."

Comment: Updated. Good Catch!